# Data from Views.Py not showing up on the template

Tags: django

I am trying to find out why some data from my *views.py* are not showing up. Here's my code

*views.py*

```
def user(request, user_id):
    profile = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
    rnk = Ranks.objects.all()
    context = {
        'profile' : profile,
        'rnk' : rnk,
    }
    return render(request, 'user/user.html', context)
```

I am trying to show, for example the `rank_name` from my model and I use `{{rnk.rank_name}}` in the HTML template but it's not showing up.

On the other hand, data from `profile` like `{{profile.user_name}}` are showing up.

Note that `rnk` and `profile` are from this model:

```
class Ranks(models.Model):
    rank_name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.br_rank_name


class User(models.Model):
    b_rank = models.ForeignKey(Ranks, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    weekly = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    biweekly = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
       return self.name
```

Here's my template

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}

<h5>{{profile.user_name}}</h5><!--This shows up-->
<p>{{rnk.rank_name}}</p>
<p>{{profile.weekly}}</p>
<span class="icon-desc">{{rnk.rank_points}} points</span>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: add your template by editing your question.

Comment: `rnk` is a list of *all* rank objects. You need to loop through them.

Comment: Just added the template in the question @JPG

Comment: @DanielRoseman how do you loop through them?

Comment: With a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `rnk` passed to the template is a *queryset* and includes multiple objects. So you need to iterate `rnk` using `for` and try to show the details for each one in your template.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <h5>{{ profile.user_name }}</h5>
    <p>{{ profile.weekly }}</p>
    {% for rank in rnk %}
        <p>{{ rank.rank_name }}</p>
        <span class="icon-desc">{{ rank.rank_points }} points</span>
        <img src="{{ rank.br_photo.url }}" height="150" alt="">
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: hey man! I just realized now that I added more data into my database that with this code, the template takes all the data from the ranks model and displays them on the page. (so if there are 100 ranks, it will show all 100. Can you please check and help me fix it? I've been trying to for an hour now... )

Comment: @RudolphMusngi you can use pagination concept to paginate your data

Comment: Not sure I understood your answer. :( I am trying to display the assigned foreign Key rank on each user. So that wehn they visit their "profile" it will show what rank they are and the details about that ran. Not sure how pagination will help. (I am new to django so I cannot wrap my head around it properly)